# Writing custom IDE on top of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, shell, ide

I wish to write my own Python IDE (just for the heck of it). I was wondering if I could use Eclipse as a foundation. This will save me from coding a whole lotta things (code editor, intellisense and so on).

To understand what I mean, please take a look at [Visual Studio Isolated Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx). I'm essentially looking for something equivalent. Searching on Google hasn't helped. Is there anything like this available in Eclipse's case?

Comment: It's certainly possible because the Defold game engine IDE is based on Eclipse ( http://www.defold.com/ ); in their FAQ they say at one point "This is due to a known bug in the underlying Eclipse framework."  I don't know any more details; I found this question as I was looking for more info on that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Eclipse is designed to have additional languages added and there is extensive support for this kind of plugin development. I'm surprised Googling didn't help - there's an [entire site](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/) dedicated to a tutorial on the basics and a [toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) for developing such things

Comment: Paul, I don't want to write a plug-in that can run along side other plug-ins in Eclipse. I want to have the whole GUI to myself (or my IDE rather). I'd like to have the equivalent of "Visual Studio Isolated Shell" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612.aspx) rather than what they call the "Visual Studio Integrated Shell" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb129445.aspx). Or is it that no such dichotomy exists the case of Eclipse, and the plug-in method is the only way?

Comment: Sorry for the excessive Visual Studio references. I'm a code monkey what was reared in the Microsoft-only cage.

Comment: I think this is plugins all the way. Eclipse has the idea of perspectives which say what you're trying to do - so when I select the Scala perspective (to take an example I'm looking at at the moment), I get Scala completion, Scala highlighting, Scala build tools/compilers etc within the normal Eclipse toolset (editors etc). This is somewhat similar to what you want to do - it's added to the standard Eclipse and implements a "complete" IDE for Scala.

Comment: Got the idea. Thanks a lot Paul.

Comment: Eclipse is just a bunch of plugins; if you want to create your own Eclipse-"product", you do so by specifying which plugins you want to include. The plugins themselves do not care if they run inside your special Python-Eclipse-IDE-product, or if they run inside a standard Eclipse IDE.